# como imprimir um texto em várias paginas utilizando o jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper

Tenho este relatório
no campo observação tem um texto que vem do banco de dados
só que ele imprime em uma pagina só, cortando o resto do texto (se tiver muito texto)

como faço pra imprimir em mais de uma página se aquele texto for maior
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O campo textfield no ireport tanto quanto no jaspersoft tem um checkbox: `Stretch With Overflow`, marque ele. Com ele marcado você poderá deixa o textfield do tamanho padrão dos outros, ele irá expandir dinamicamente de acordo com o tamanho do seu texto.

[image: Marque o checkbox destacado.]

Comment: Eu estou com um problema referente aos campos que eu coloco na aba `Details`, nunca é exibido nada que esta nessa aba na hora de gerar o relatório, mas nas outras abas aparece normalmente os conteúdos que eu coloco na hora de gerar o relatório, será que você teria alguma ideia de o que posso estar fazendo errado para causar isso? Qualquer dica será muito bem vinda